# How to break line between 2 variables

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to have something like this:

```php
Rue Félicité Beaudin
13004 Marseille
```

And in twig I've got 3 variables :

- user.address
- user.zipcode
- user.city

I've tried to do :

```
{{ company.address~"\n"~company.zipcode|raw|nl2br }} {{ company.city }}
```

but no success, is there a way to break the line between 2 variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filters willy only apply the closest variable met, meaning the filters will only be applied to `company.zipcode`.

You need to add parentheses to span across multiple elements,

```
{{ (company.address~"\n"~company.zipcode)|raw|nl2br }}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/q48qni)